# Can we select Firestore Native Mode using Python script or some api call not UI?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build a GCP project , in which i need a Firestore DB , but i cant ask customer to select DB mode from UI.
I want my python code to init firestore DB in Native mode.

Comment: Not clear what you have here, Sumit. Give some context, explain what you have (backend, frontend). Who is customer? What is GCP?

Comment: @Brandt. GCP is google cloud project,  If i am trying to create a database via Firestore(which is a key value DB inside GCP) It operates in Two modes. So i was setting up a GCP project in which i want to setup DB , but there is no option to select mode of Database via CLI , always we have to select From GUI.